# Whenever I try to update another item error appears ,how can I solve it?

Tags: flutter, dart

Exception has occurred.
FlutterError `setState()` or `markNeedsBuild()` called during build.
This `TextFormField` widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.

A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building.

This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which `setState()` or `markNeedsBuild()` was called was:

TextFormField
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
Builder)

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
    import 'package:project_1_money_management/Screens/Home/home_screen.dart';
    import 'package:project_1_money_management/db/transaction_db.dart';
    import 'package:project_1_money_management/models/category_model.dart';
    import 'package:project_1_money_management/update/update_category.dart';
    
    import '../Screens/Adding_items/Widgets/date_picker.dart';
    import '../db/category_db.dart';
    import '../models/transactions_model.dart';
    
    final purposecontroller = TextEditingController();
    
    final amountcontroller = TextEditingController();
    
    class UpdateScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      final TransactionModel value;
      const UpdateScreen({Key? key, required this.value}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<UpdateScreen> createState() => _UpdateScreenState();
    }
    
    class _UpdateScreenState extends State<UpdateScreen> {
      CategoryType? type;
      DateTime? _date;
    
      CategoryModel? cat;
      @override
      // ignore: must_call_super
      void initState() {
        CategoryDB().refreshUI();
        TransactionDB.instance.refresh();
        super.initState();
        amountcontroller.text = widget.value.amount.toString();
        purposecontroller.text = widget.value.purpose;
        _date = widget.value.date;
        cat = widget.value.category;
        type = widget.value.type;
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 35, 32, 32),
          body: SafeArea(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Add Transactions',
                    style: GoogleFonts.inconsolata(
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 40,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8),
                  child: Card(
                    color: const Color.fromARGB(48, 175, 171, 171),
                    elevation: 60,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, bottom: 40),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          ElevatedButton.icon(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              primary: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 251,
                                  253), //change background color of button
                              onPrimary: const Color.fromARGB(
                                  255, 56, 120, 204), //change text color of button
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              ),
                              elevation: 15.0,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              selectDates(context);
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
                            label: Text(
                              '${_date!.day}/${_date!.month}/${_date!.year}',
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  CateogryUpdate(cats: cat!, types: type!),
                                ],
                              )),
                          Form(
                              child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: amountcontroller,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                                    filled: true,
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: purposecontroller,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        vertical: 40.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                                    filled: true,
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )),
                          ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(19),
                            child: Stack(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Positioned.fill(
                                  child: Container(
                                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                                        colors: <Color>[
                                          Color.fromARGB(255, 81, 185, 67),
                                          Color.fromARGB(255, 32, 188, 32),
                                          Color.fromARGB(255, 52, 181, 32),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                TextButton(
                                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                                    primary:
                                        const Color.fromARGB(255, 247, 247, 247),
                                    textStyle: GoogleFonts.inconsolata(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    await update(
                                      widget.value.id!,
                                      amountcontroller.text,
                                    );
                                  },
                                  child: const Text('     Update     '),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 14,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      selectDates(BuildContext context) async {
        selected = await showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: _date!,
          firstDate: DateTime(2021),
          lastDate: DateTime.now(),
        );
        if (selected != null && selected != _date!) {
          setState(() {
            _date = selected!;
          });
        }
      }
    
      update(String id, String amt) async {
        final _update = TransactionModel(
          amount: double.tryParse(amt)!,
          purpose: purposecontroller.text,
          category: cat!,
          date: _date!,
          type: type,
          id: id,
        );
    
        await TransactionDB.instance.updateTransact(_update);
        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (route) => const ScreenHome()));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code before seState();

```
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (selected != null && selected != _date!) {
          setState(() {
          _date = selected!;
          });
        }
     });
```